# How to extract SIM card Data in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-contentprovider

I want to start a project for an android application where a user can apply for a loan. For this to work effectively I need to get some data from the SIM card which includes the date the sim card started working on the phone(Date of the first insertion).

Is this possible?
How can I do this, please?

Comment: I have no idea how to do that, but it doesn't sound like a reliable way to secure a loan.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible. There is Telephony API in android which provides APIs for monitoring the basic phone information, such as the network type and connection state, plus utilities for manipulating phone number strings etc.

[check here to know more](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/package-summary)

Comment: Thanks, I checked out the doc but there isn't any API to access the date when a sim card was inserted

Comment: Answers should be in the form of code.  A comment with a link to a page that has no information is not an answer.